# Using OAuth2 token to authenticate to an API hosted on Google App Engine?

Tags: java, android, google-app-engine, authentication, oauth

I'm building a backend for my Android app using GAE, and I'd like to authenticate users with their Google accounts, sent from the Android app.

Before OAuth2, you were able to use a Cookie retrieved from the `_ah/login` endpoint to authenticate users into your web app, but that method is deprecated and I'd like to be able to use the updated OAuth2 method.

In my Android app I've been able to generate a JSON Web Token using the following line:

```
String jwt =  GoogleAuthUtil.getToken(FamiliarActivity.this, Plus.AccountApi.getAccountName(mGoogleApiClient), "audience:server:client_id:1234567.apps.googleusercontent.com");
```

or an OAuth token:

```
String oauth2 =  GoogleAuthUtil.getToken(FamiliarActivity.this, Plus.AccountApi.getAccountName(mGoogleApiClient), "oauth2:server:client_id:1234567.apps.googleusercontent.com:api_scope:https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.login");
```

Either, manually, I can pass to my API and validate against Google. But I haven't been able to figure out a way to use a token like this to trigger authentication in GAE like the Cookie used to. The documentation seems to indicate passing it as a header: `Authorization: Bearer <TOKEN>` but that doesn't seem to work.

What is the correct way to retrieve and pass a token to my GAE endpoint so that it authenticates the user?

Comment: I know answers shouldn't be links, but anyway, here is what I personally looked at to get a better understanding of App engine + Oauth 2.0  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HoUdWBzUZ-M

Comment: Doesn't GAE have an API that lets your log users in manually (IIRC, it used to)? If so, implement custom authentication using filters, etc. and just call the API after you verify the token.

Comment: Another idea is to compare the bearer tokens sent by browser login with the the tokens you get from GoogleAuthUtil. This is a different method, that should work, but it requires a full account access token. It basically simulates Web login, and then saves all cookies, so you can send them with subsequent requests: https://github.com/AndlyticsProject/andlytics/blob/dev/src/com/github/andlyticsproject/console/v2/OauthAccountManagerAuthenticator.java

Answer (score 0):

The correct and documented way to accomplish this is to:

1) [Create](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/endpoints/auth) an OAuth protected endpoint with the

```
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.login
```

or

```
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email
```

scope and authorized Client ID for the Android client app.

2) [Generate](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/endpoints/gen_clients) client library and [integrate](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/endpoints/consume_android#making_authenticated_calls) with your app.

Comment: All 3 links in this answer have been deprecated.